# Retrieving exif tags from GeoTiff with GDAL?

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, metadata, digital-image-processing, exif

I work on toolkit that automatically classifies data from a bunch of aerial cameras. Each camera uses geotagging to store position and time metadata in EXIF tags.

When I use GDAL (I use version 2.0.2 on a device running debian 8) to equalize the images all additional tags are lost. How can I copy these tags into the new file with gdal, to give the process queue the self contained infos.

Example:

Phil Harveys exiftool gives me a clue whats in the box. For example fom this camera:

```
$ exiftool flir_cam2_20180528172334.524_1051.tif
ExifTool Version Number         : 10.20
File Name                       : flir_cam2_20180528172334.524_1051.tif
Directory                       : .
File Size                       : 274 kB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2018:05:28 18:33:13+02:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2018:08:01 17:59:54+02:00
File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2018:08:01 17:15:10+02:00
File Permissions                : rw-------
File Type                       : TIFF
File Type Extension             : tif
MIME Type                       : image/tiff
Exif Byte Order                 : Little-endian (Intel, II)
Image Width                     : 640
Image Height                    : 512
Bits Per Sample                 : 16
Compression                     : LZW
Photometric Interpretation      : BlackIsZero
Strip Offsets                   : (Binary data 564 bytes, use -b option to extract)
Samples Per Pixel               : 1
Rows Per Strip                  : 6
Strip Byte Counts               : (Binary data 429 bytes, use -b option to extract)
Planar Configuration            : Chunky
Predictor                       : Horizontal differencing
GPS Latitude Ref                : North
GPS Longitude Ref               : East
GPS Altitude Ref                : Above Sea Level
GPS Time Stamp                  : 15:23:34
GPS Map Datum                   : WGS-84
GPS Date Stamp                  : 2018:05:28
GPS Altitude                    : 309.7 m Above Sea Level
GPS Date/Time                   : 2018:05:28 15:23:34Z
GPS Latitude                    : 48 deg 19' 36.46" N
GPS Longitude                   : 15 deg 53' 26.60" E
GPS Position                    : 48 deg 19' 36.46" N, 15 deg 53' 26.60" E
Image Size                      : 640x512
Megapixels                      : 0.328
```

gdalinfo -listmdd $file is blind on this eye.

```
gdal -listmdd 

$ gdalinfo -listmdd flir_cam2_20180528172334.524_1051.tif 
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: cam2_20180528172334.524_1051.tiff
Size is 640, 512
Coordinate System is `'
Metadata domains:
  IMAGE_STRUCTURE
  EXIF
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=LZW
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0,  512.0)
Upper Right (  640.0,    0.0)
Lower Right (  640.0,  512.0)
Center      (  320.0,  256.0)
Band 1 Block=640x6 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Gray
```

The resulting image from the processing was created with the GDAL command stack (pseudo code):

```
newHandle = GDALCreateCopy(gdalGeoTiffDriver, 'equal-16bit.tif', origFileHandle, strict, optionForCompress, NULL, NULL)  
...do some image processing stuff 
GDALFlushCache(newHandle);
GDALClose(newHandle);
```

After the process the info is gone:

```
$ exiftool equal-16bit.tif 
ExifTool Version Number         : 10.20
File Name                       : equal-16bit.tif
Directory                       : .
File Size                       : 362 kB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2018:08:02 17:51:10+02:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2018:08:02 17:51:36+02:00
File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2018:08:02 17:51:10+02:00
File Permissions                : rw-r--r--
File Type                       : TIFF
File Type Extension             : tif
MIME Type                       : image/tiff
Exif Byte Order                 : Little-endian (Intel, II)
Image Width                     : 640
Image Height                    : 512
Bits Per Sample                 : 16
Compression                     : LZW
Photometric Interpretation      : BlackIsZero
Samples Per Pixel               : 1
Planar Configuration            : Chunky
Predictor                       : None
Tile Width                      : 256
Tile Length                     : 256
Tile Offsets                    : (Binary data 37 bytes, use -b option to extract)
Tile Byte Counts                : (Binary data 35 bytes, use -b option to extract)
Sample Format                   : Unsigned
Image Size                      : 640x512
Megapixels                      : 0.328
```

Is there a possibility to use the routines:

```
oldMetadata = GDALGetMetadata( oldDatasetHandle, domain );
GDALSetMetadata(newDatasetHandle, oldMetadata, domain);
```

to copy the infos and which domain I have to use?

Comment: Have you tried piexif (python library)?

Comment: No, if have work in a freepascal  with a the gdal library in the environment and check only the capabilities of the lib.

Comment: Ah OK I thought we were working with Python like most of us in the GIS world. But there is probably a library in the language of your choice to parse EXIF tags? Does the solution absolutely have to be tied to using GDAL for that?

Comment: Yes, I work with the C-bindings of GDAL, otherwise I would use Phil Harveys exiftool.

Comment: Something like this: 
`exiftool −overwrite_original_in_place -r -tagsFromFile source.tif -gps:all dest.tif`

Answer (score 2):

I will close that request due to the answers of a Q&A on the *GDAL issue forum*.

https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/828

At the moment gdal cannot properly copy raster metadata from the source [EXIF IFD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exif) to the [IFD](http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/tiff/tiff_summary.pdf) of the copied image.